# Flutter how to enter full screen mode

Tags: fullscreen, flutter

I use setEnabledSystemUIOverlays to hide status bar and virtual button bar.

But there are blanks on the top and bottom of the screen *(as seen in the photo)*:

[image: Screen Photo]

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: "Test",
      home: new MyHomePage(title: "Test"),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(title),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tried to run your code on my phone, both portrait and landscape. I guess you are using tablet?

Comment: Yes,I'm using asus tablet.Is this probably the reason?

Comment: On my phone, the blanks still exists

Comment: Strange. It works for me

Comment: How about try it on Android Simulator? and iOS Simulator?

Comment: Everything is fine on iOS, but it still happened on Android Simulator.

Comment: I think it only happens on Android

Comment: What version of sdk are you using? I'm using the latest beta.

Comment: Flutter 0.3.2
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.48.0.flutter-fe606f890b

Comment: It's the same as I'm using. So weird.

Comment: I tested here on Samsung S6 Edge and Samsung Tab E. Both work. Try to reinstall Flutter?

Comment: Didn't you see the blanks?

Comment: No blank on my side

Comment: I just reinstalled flutter SDK, but I still see those blank. Too strange...

Answer (score 7):

set resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false to Scaffold.

```
   return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
   );
```

Answer (score 7):

this it work perfect for me:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // To make this screen full screen.
    // It will hide status bar and notch.
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

    // full screen image for splash screen.
    return Container(
            child: new Image.asset('assets/splash.png', fit: BoxFit.fill));
      }
    }
```

import this

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be [an issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18671) on Android. For some reason it does not recalculate the [SafeArea](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

### flutter 2.x:

- still has this problem.
- `// resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false` not work for me.

### my solution:

- `Container.height =  Get.height`       // set `max height`
- `Container.child.image.fit = BoxFit.fill` // with this
- this work for me, under `flutter 2.2.0`

### example full screen page:

- full code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';


import '../controllers/splash_controller.dart';

class SplashScreenView extends GetView<SplashController> {
  final SplashController c = Get.find();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        /// key! fix full screen
        height: Get.height,

        ///
        child: Lottie.asset(
          /// image file:
          AppConfig.splash1,

          /// key! fix full screen
          fit: BoxFit.fill,

          ///
          controller: c.animationController,
          frameRate: FrameRate(60),
          repeat: true,

          ///
          delegates: LottieDelegates(
            text: (initialText) => 'test',
          ),

          onLoaded: (composition) {
            c.animationController..duration = composition.duration;
          },
        ),
      ),

      /// not work
      // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }
}
```